# Amazon widget not showing on PC

Tags: cross-browser

I have added an Amazon associate widget to my website.  On my mac the widget displays fine.  On my PC it does not display at all.  At first I thought it was a difference between browsers, firefox on my PC and safari on my mac.  But I installed firefox on my mac and it shows up fine there as well.  I also tried it in IE on my pc, obviously it didn't work.  Whats going on here.  What could be causing firefox to perform differently on different OS's?  If it helps I'm running the site on google app engine.  I looked in fire bug.  On the mac, the js seems to create an embed element.  This does not happen on the PC.  I don't know where to go from here.  If anyone needs more info let me know.

I am posting the widget using Widget-Source But I have also tried just the normal page link and I'm encountering the same problems.  blow is the code I'm testing copied directly from the Amazon Widget-Source site.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var amzn_wdgt={widget:'MP3Clips'};
amzn_wdgt.tag='loot03-20';
amzn_wdgt.widgetType='ASINList';
amzn_wdgt.ASIN='B0011Z0YR2,B00137W4P8,B0013G0PG4,B001AU8ZLK,B001AUCJZ8,B001AUEMDK,B001AU8YB6,B001AU8YBQ,B001AU8YCK,B001AUCK2U,B001AUEMFS,B001AUCK52,B001AU6XE6,B001AUEMH6';
amzn_wdgt.title='What I\'ve been listening to lately...';
amzn_wdgt.width='250';
amzn_wdgt.height='250';
amzn_wdgt.shuffleTracks='True';
amzn_wdgt.marketPlace='US';
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://wms.assoc-amazon.com/20070822/US/js/swfobject_1_5.js'>
</script>
```

Comment: Should the latter script tag (calling the 'swfobject') not precede the first tag? (Genuinely, this is a question, I don't know either way...)

Comment: This is an exact copy from the amazon site, so I think the order is correct. I figure the first script is setting variables used by the second.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: Seems to be specific only to my development machine.  I haven't fixed it yet but it does work on other PC's.

Comment: So I'm an idiot and had ad blocker plug-in that was blocking the amazon pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem as Lumpy, and yes (duh), after disabling Adblock Plus all was well. Thanks for the tip!